# Python - Remove all characters until final alpha letter in string

Tags: python, string

I have several strings where I need to remove all characters until the final alphabetical letter. I'm trying to keep the final numerical tag and store it into a variable. If there is no numerical tag at the end (like in the case of `Serial` and `Management`), then the variable should be empty. The strings that need editing look like so:

```
Ethernet5/3                   # Store '5/3'
TengigabitEthernet3/1/1       # Store '3/1/1'
100 GigabitEthernet2/6/1      # Store '2/6/1'
Management                    # Store ''
Serial                        # Store ''
```

I can't strip everything until the first number because there are some strings that begin with numbers, like `100 GigabitEthernet2/6/1`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Reverse the string, find the index of the first alpha character, and slice off from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To follow Lawrence's comment, you can use a combination of reversing a string, [`itertools.takewhile()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) and [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
from itertools import takewhile

l = [
    "Ethernet5/3",
    "TengigabitEthernet3/1/1",
    "100 GigabitEthernet2/6/1",
    "Management",
    "Serial"
]

for item in l:
    print("".join(takewhile(lambda c: not c.isalpha(), item[::-1]))[::-1])
```

Prints:

```
5/3
3/1/1
2/6/1
<empty string>
<empty string>
```

---

Another option would be to use regular expressions and capture in a [group](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#grouping) digits and slashes at the end of a string (`$` in the expression):

```
import re

l = [
    "Ethernet5/3",
    "TengigabitEthernet3/1/1",
    "100 GigabitEthernet2/6/1",
    "Management",
    "Serial"
]

pattern = re.compile(r"([0-9/]+)$")
for item in l:
    match = pattern.search(item)
    print(match.group(1) if match else "No match")
```

Prints:

```
5/3
3/1/1
2/6/1
No match
No match
```